# How to wait for async method results in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, flutter-dependencies

Currently me and my team members are working in a Mobile application. These application contains five pages. In all the five pages we have a bottom drawer to display the list of apps. Actually we are using flutter's **installed_apps** package for displaying the list of installed apps. But the main problem here is...in order to avoid the code redundancy we refactor the bottom drawer code into a separate **bottom_drawer_class** widget. But the problem here is **if we use a separate file, the async service method return the empty list of apps**. if we embedd the bottom_drawer_class inside the main dart file, it is working finely. We dont know how to get rid of it.

Our code:
if we not refactor the **main.dart** file

```
import 'package:bottom_drawer/bottom_drawer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:installed_apps/installed_apps.dart';
import 'package:installed_apps/app_info.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  final double _headerHeight = 60.0;
  final double _bodyHeight = 300.0;
  final BottomDrawerController _controller = BottomDrawerController();
  List listApps = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getApp();
  }

  void _getApp() async {
    List<AppInfo> apps = await InstalledApps.getInstalledApps(true, true);

for (var app in apps) {
  var item = AppModel(
    title: app.name!,
    package: app.getVersionInfo(),
    icon: app.icon!,
  );
  listApps.add(item);
}
print(listApps.length);
//reloading state
setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Bottom drawer example app'),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            _buildBottomDrawer(context),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBottomDrawer(BuildContext context) {

    return BottomDrawer(
      header: _buildBottomDrawerHead(context),
      body: _buildBottomDrawerBody(context),
      headerHeight: _headerHeight,
      drawerHeight: _bodyHeight,
      color: Colors.white,
      controller: _controller,
      boxShadow: const [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.black12,
          blurRadius: 10,
          spreadRadius: 3,
          offset: Offset(5, -2), // changes position of shadow
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBottomDrawerHead(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: _headerHeight,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(45)),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: const [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 0.0,
              right: 160.0,
              top: 27.0,
            ),
            child: Text(
              "Most frequently used apps",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontFamily: 'inter'),
            ),
          ),
          Spacer(),
          Divider(
            height: 0.1,
            thickness: 4,
            color: Colors.black12,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBottomDrawerBody(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: _bodyHeight,
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: listApps.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) => Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                  bottom: BorderSide(
                    width: .1,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: ListTile(
                leading: Image.memory(listApps[i].icon),
                title: Text(listApps[i].title),
                subtitle: Text(listApps[i].package),
                trailing: const Icon(Icons.timer),
                visualDensity: const VisualDensity(vertical: -1),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AppModel {
  final String title;
  final String package;
  final Uint8List icon;

  AppModel({required this.title, required this.package, required this.icon});
}
```

it will give the desired list of results. But if we refactor the code in separate file the list remains empty.
**refactored files**
**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'bottom_drawer_class.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Bottom drawer example app'),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: const [
            BottomDrawerGeneral(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**bottom_drawer_class.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:bottom_drawer/bottom_drawer.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:installed_apps/installed_apps.dart';
import 'package:installed_apps/app_info.dart';

class BottomDrawerGeneral extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomDrawerGeneral({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BottomDrawerGeneral> createState() => BottomDrawerGeneralState();
}

class BottomDrawerGeneralState extends State<BottomDrawerGeneral> {
  final double _headerHeight = 60.0;
  final double _bodyHeight = 300.0;
  final BottomDrawerController _controller = BottomDrawerController();
  List listApps = [];
  void _getApp() async {
    List<AppInfo> apps = await InstalledApps.getInstalledApps(true, true);
    for (var app in apps) {
      var item = AppModel(
        title: app.name!,
        package: app.getVersionInfo(),
        icon: app.icon!,
      );
      listApps.add(item);
    }
    //reloading state
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getApp();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomDrawer(
      header: _buildBottomDrawerHead(context),
      body: _buildBottomDrawerBody(context),
      headerHeight: _headerHeight,
      drawerHeight: _bodyHeight,
      color: Colors.white,
      controller: _controller,
      boxShadow: const [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.black12,
          blurRadius: 10,
          spreadRadius: 3,
          offset: Offset(5, -2), // changes position of shadow
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBottomDrawerHead(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: _headerHeight,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(45)),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: const [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 0.0,
              right: 160.0,
              top: 27.0,
            ),
            child: Text(
              "Most frequently used apps",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontFamily: 'inter'),
            ),
          ),
          Spacer(),
          Divider(
            height: 0.1,
            thickness: 4,
            color: Colors.black12,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBottomDrawerBody(BuildContext context) {
    print(listApps.length);

    return SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: _bodyHeight,
        child: listApps.isNotEmpty
            ? ListView.builder(
                itemCount: listApps.length,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) => Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border(
                          bottom: BorderSide(
                            width: .1,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: ListTile(
                        leading: Image.memory(listApps[i].icon),
                        title: Text(listApps[i].title),
                        subtitle: Text(listApps[i].package),
                        trailing: const Icon(Icons.timer),
                        visualDensity: const VisualDensity(vertical: -1),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 10,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) => Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border(
                          bottom: BorderSide(
                            width: .1,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: const ListTile(
                        leading: Icon(Icons.app_registration),
                        title: Text("listApps[i].title"),
                        subtitle: Text("listApps[i].package"),
                        trailing: Icon(Icons.timer),
                        visualDensity: VisualDensity(vertical: -1),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ));
  }
}

class AppModel {
  final String title;
  final String package;
  final Uint8List icon;

  AppModel({required this.title, required this.package, required this.icon});
}
```

experts can help with my problem :)..
if you found the solution, please explain the problem with our approach of refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

In the extracted widget a set state is missing

```dart
void _getApp() async {
    List<AppInfo> apps = await InstalledApps.getInstalledApps(true, true);
    for (var app in apps) {
      var item = AppModel(
        title: app.name!,
        package: app.getVersionInfo(),
        icon: app.icon!,
      );
      listApps.add(item);
    }
    setState((){}}; //<--- here
  }
```